# How can I call a java.util.function.Function outside the class where it has been declared?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am totally new to java functional programming and the Function library and I want to use it for *apply* function. I want to be able to transform an object into another type.

Let's say I have those 2 objects:

```
public class UserOne {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   ... constructor/getters and setters
}

public class UserTwo {
   private String name;
   ... constructor/get/set
}
```

Then i create a new class with my Function:

```
public class TransformUser1ToUser2 {
   Function<UserOne, UserTwo> user1ToUser2 = new Function<UserOne, UserTwo>() {
      public UserTwo apply(UserOne userone) {
         UserTwo usertwo = new usertwo;
         usertwo.setname(t.getFirstName() + " " + t.getLastName());
         return usertwo;
      }
   }
}
```

Now how should I do to call the *apply* method in another class, let's say:

```
public class MainClass {
   public static void main() {
      UserOne userone = new UserOne("firstName", "lastName");
      UserTwo usertwo = CALL Function to transform userone to usertwo
   ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Your example falls short of your goal to use functional style, but to answer your question about how to call it, you have chosen to place your Function  as a member variable of `TransformUser1ToUser2`.  So if these are in the same package, you could create an instance of `TransformUser1ToUser2` and then call the `apply()` function like this: `UserTwo userTwo = new TransformUser1ToUser2().user1ToUser2.apply(userone);`

Comment: ok i get it and the fact that i would have to create an instance makes me loose the goal to use functional style.

Comment: Well, nothing says you can't use anonymous classes to create your functional types but the cool new way to create functional types is to use lambdas like `Function<UserOne, UserTwo> user1ToUser2 = u1 -> new UserTwo(...);`

Comment: ok i think i need to learn more on functional prog and lambdas...

Comment: It takes a little getting used to but the thing that helped me the most is understanding that the compiler needs 2 things to generate a function -- a method signature (parameters, parameter types & return type) and a body. The functional type's function (e.g. Function's apply()) supplies the signature, and the lambda expression supplies the body.  They are married into a function when you assign the lambda to a functional type.

Comment: The other key thing for me was understanding that `u1 -> new User2(whatever)` is short for `(User1 u1) -> {  return new User2(whatever); }` which looks much more like a function (it's just missing a function name and it has that `->` thrown in, but in all other respects it has all of the information that any function has)

Comment: if you make user1ToUser2 static, then you wouldn't need to create an instance of TransformUser1ToUser2. In fact, the latter class would probably be better some utility class that collects static function definitions, and you could name it accordingly. Or you define user1ToUser2 as a static member directly in your main-class. When you then in addition use the lambda-notation as suggested by @Hank D, your code already gets much simpler.

Comment: you could also make 
`TransformUser1ToUser2 implements Function<UserOne, UserTwo> {@Override public UserTwo apply(UserOne userone) {...}}`.
Then you would call it as: `new TransformUser1ToUser2().apply(userone)`, without reference to an extra member field.